# How can I convert csv to RDD of labeled points?

Tags: python, csv, pyspark, rdd

I want to perform a decision tree regression on a dataset in csv. It is required that I do it using RDD. I tried the following to convert the dataframe to RDD:

```
pp_df = spark.read.csv("/usr/local/spark/data/hour.csv",header=True,inferSchema=True)
pp_df = pp_df.rdd.map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x[10], x[:10])).collect()
```

Then I try to split the data for training and testing :

```
(trainingData, testData) = pp_df.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3])
```

And I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'randomSplit'
```

Why it returns a list instead and How can I properly convert the csv to RDD labeled data ?

Comment: in the title you mentioned RDD (resilient distributed dataset) and later you are mentioning RRD (round robin database).. I know you probably meant RDD because of spark usage, but please be consistent..

Answer (score 0):

`pp_df = pp_df.rdd.map(lambda x: LabeledPoint(x[10], x[:10])).collect()`returns an array not an RDD. Thus you can't use the `randomSplit` method on this.

Spark Actions : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Do you know how do I return a RRD labeled dataset ?

Comment: You should try something out without collect().